# Unknown name value [] for enum class

Tags: hibernate, enums

I got below stacktrace
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [NC-17] for enum class [com.ecw.pojo.Rating]
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$NamedEnumValueMapper.fromName(EnumType.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$NamedEnumValueMapper.getValue(EnumType.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1627)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1514)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2263)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder$LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializer.initialize(LegacyBatchingCollectionInitializerBuilder.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1893)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:551)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.toString(PersistentSet.java:316)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
    at util.TestMapping.main(TestMapping.java:35)

```
My enum class as below

public enum Rating {

    G("G"),
    PG("PG"),
    PG13("PG-13"),
    R("R"),
    NC17("NC-17");

    private String value;

    private Rating(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.value; //will return , or ' instead of COMMA or APOSTROPHE
    }
}
```

And in entity as below

```
@Column(name = "rating")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Rating rating;
```

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate doesn't care about your custom value attribute. It uses the name of the enum: `NC17`, not `NC-17`.

If you want to use `NC-17`, you need a Hibernate custom type of a JPA attribute converter.

Comment: Can you please help me how to create it? If any example then send me link of it. Thanks for quick reply @JB Nizet

Comment: Google "JPA attribute converter", click the first link, and read. Then try to adapt the example(s) to your specific case.